# Rally Java: Duplicate test case getting created

Tags: java, rally

I have built a Rally dependency, which auto creates test case, folder in Test Plan. While creating test case it checks first if there any any existing test case with same name, else it creates new test case.
This was working while total test case size was small, while the test case size increased, i am seeing duplicate test cases are created. So I made thread to wait for few seconds (Thread.sleep(8000)) after checking existing scenarios and then creating new scenario. It works by this way.

Is there better way to handle & implement this to handle any size of test case. Please advice.

```
String tcName = rallyMethods.getTestScenarios(parentFolder, scenarioName);
Thread.sleep(8000);

if (tcName == null) {
 rallyMethods.createTestCase(parentFolder, scenarioName);
 Thread.sleep(8000);
} else {
   rallyMethods.updateTestCase(parentFolder, scenarioName);
   Thread.sleep(8000);
}
```

```
 public String getTestScenarios(String parentFolderName, String ScenarioName) throws Throwable {
        String sName = null;
        String pFolder;

        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testCaseRequest.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        testCaseRequest.setPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Workspace", "Project", "TestFolder"));
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", ScenarioName));
        testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(WORKSPACE_ID);
        testCaseRequest.setProject(PROJECT_ID);
        QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = query(testCaseRequest);
        int testCaseCount = testCaseQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
        // System.out.println("TestCaseCount:" + testCaseCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < testCaseCount; i++) {
            JsonObject scenarioObj = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            String scenarioName = String.valueOf(scenarioObj.get("Name").getAsString());
            JsonElement pFolderObj = scenarioObj.get("TestFolder");

            if (!(pFolderObj.isJsonNull())) {
                JsonObject tFolderObj = scenarioObj.get("TestFolder").getAsJsonObject();
                pFolder = String.valueOf(tFolderObj.get("Name").getAsString());

                if (parentFolderName.equalsIgnoreCase(pFolder)) {
                    sName = scenarioName;
                    logger.info("Test Scenarios identified in Rally: " + sName);
                } else {
                    logger.info("Scenario, " + ScenarioName + " not found, New Scenario will be created in Rally");
                }
            }
        }
        return sName;
    }
```

```
 public void createTestCase(String parentFolderName, String testCaseName) throws Throwable {
        String tcName = null;
        String userID = readUser();

        // Query Child Folders:
        QueryRequest testFolderRequest = new QueryRequest("TestFolder");
        testFolderRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "Workspace", "Project"));
        testFolderRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", parentFolderName));
        testFolderRequest.setWorkspace(WORKSPACE_ID);
        testFolderRequest.setProject(PROJECT_ID);
        QueryResponse testFolderQueryResponse = query(testFolderRequest);

        int folderCount = testFolderQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < folderCount; i++) {
            String testFolderRef = testFolderQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
            JsonObject testFolderObj = testFolderQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            String pFolder = String.valueOf(testFolderObj.get("Name").getAsString());

            if (pFolder.equalsIgnoreCase(parentFolderName)) {

                //System.out.println("Creating a test case...");
                JsonObject newTC = new JsonObject();
                newTC.addProperty("Name", testCaseName);
                newTC.addProperty("Workspace", WORKSPACE_ID);
                newTC.addProperty("Project", PROJECT_ID);
                newTC.addProperty("Description", "Selenium Automated TestCase");
                newTC.addProperty("TestFolder", testFolderRef);
                newTC.addProperty("Method", "Automated");
                newTC.addProperty("Type", "Functional");
                if (!(userID == null)) {
                    newTC.addProperty("Owner", userID);
                }

                CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcase", newTC);
                CreateResponse createResponse = create(createRequest);
                if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                    JsonObject tcObj = createResponse.getObject();
                    tcName = String.valueOf(tcObj.get("Name").getAsString());
                    logger.info("Created test scenario name is: " + tcName);
                } else {
                    String[] createErrors;
                    createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    logger.info("Error while creating test scenario below parent folder!");
                    for (int j = 0; j < createErrors.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                        logger.info(createErrors[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I'm not too familiar with the Java REST toolkit, but I can't think of a reason why a larger set of test cases in the workspace would cause the query to fail like that.

Did you try checking `testCaseQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()`? If it returns false, can you see what the error is? `testCaseQueryResponse.getErrors()`

My first thoughts are that you should provide a reasonable value for the limit and pageSize parameters, rather than passing `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. And second, rather than checking if the returned test cases are in the specified parent folder, you should include a query filter to filter the test cases results on `TestFolder.Name = parentFolderName`. Then you should only be expecting either 1 or 0 results returned (assuming that you're expecting all test cases within a test folder to have unique names).

Comment: Yes. I have added condition to check if response was successful and then proceed. Actually when I noticed during debug for some scenarios, it skips the process inbetween abruptly while creating new scenario but handling after thread.sleep() it works fine. It's weird why it does that ... still trying to find the reason why it does that.